# Add new element after another

Tags: erlang

I'm making a function with recursion that adds element A after element of list which equals B. So it should look like this:

```
func(20,4,[1,2,4,5,4]) -> [1,2,4,20,5,4,20]
```

This is what I've got:

```
-module (task).
-export ([vst/3]).

vst(A,B,[]) -> 0;
vst(A,B,[H|T]) when H=:=B -> [H,A|T)].
```

How I should do this with recursion?

Comment: SO it is not place for solve your homeworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. You need to return `[]` in the base case.
2. You need to recursively call `vst` in `H=:=B` case.
3. You need to handle the case when `H=/=B`.

Final code:

```
vst(_A, _B, []) -> [];
vst(A, B, [H|T]) when H =:= B -> [H, A | vst(A, B, T)];
vst(A, B, [H|T]) -> [H | vst(A, B, T)].
```

```
1> task:vst(20, 4, [1,2,4,5,4]).
[1,2,4,20,5,4,20]
2> task:vst(20, 4, [4,4,4]).
[4,20,4,20,4,20]
3> task:vst(20, 4, []).
[]
```

Comment: I guess better use the pattern matching instead guard: `vst(A, B, [B|T]) -> [B, A | vst(A, B, T)];`